# Is possible force Geoserver answer to lowercase?

Tags: geoserver

I use **Geoserver** ( 2.5.1 ) wfs service to fill some tables in my web client. I want have the possibility to install my geoserver on **Oracle** or **PostGIS**. Unfortunately the first have the tables and his fields uppercase and the second all lowercase. So I have to manage this client side, but I won't. 

 Is possible to force the Geoserver answer fields and tables names to **lowercase** ( or uppercase ) ?

Comment: `So I have to manage this client side, but I won't.` why not?

Comment: @njzk2 Because the client is already done and I don't want to edit it, if is possible to makes changes only Geoserver side. And more over, the client make a lot of iteraction with Geoserver and with another server, for some webservices. I tried to lowercase all the request, but in that case the data too are put lowercase, so is not a good solution. So to manage this in the client i need to parse all the geoserver request and lowercase only the tables and the fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can [force upper-case](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase.html) or lower-case request using web-server like apache as a proxy. 
put a web-server layer infront of your databases, and use the Htaccess Rewrite to redirect Uppercase to LowCase